# Method for inferring tree structure from messy sequence data

Tags: natural-language, networks, sequence-analysis

I have data about case events in criminal cases. These data are in the form of sequence like

```
DEFENDANT ARRAIGNED
PLEA OF GUILTY
DEFENDANT SENTENCED

DEFENDANT ARRAIGNED
PLEA OF NOT GUILTY
JURY SELECTED
VERDICT OF GUILTY
DEFENDANT SENTENCED

DEFENDANT ARRAIGNED
PLEA OF NOT GUILTY
JURY SELECTED
VERDICT OF NOT GUILTY
```

The data would be well modelled by a tree. For these three little cases

```
                       DEFENDANT ARRAIGNED
                      /                   \
        PLEA OF GUILTY                     PLEA OF NOT GUILTY
               |                                   |
        DEFENDANT SENTENCED                JURY SELECTED
                                           /            \
                              VERDICT OF GUILTY      VERDICT OF NOT GUILTY
                                      |
                              DEFENDANT SENTENCED
```

Unfortunately, there are about 700 events, hundreds of thousands of cases, and the data is messy with some events missing when they should appear.

What techniques would you suggest for inferring a tree structure from this type of messy sequence data? I feel like this problem may be related to dependency parsing.

Comment: This seems, in large part, tautological or deterministic in its logic to me. In other words, if a defendant is "Arraigned" and the next piece of info is "Verdict of Guilty," then the sequence is clear and treating it as a combinatoric set of all possible combinations would work. However, if a defendant is "Arraigned" and the next piece of information in the sequence is "Defendant Sentenced" then one could build some sort of probabilistic model for inferring the missing step Contingency table analysis on the set of "full information" to develop the transition probabilities would be one approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten pretty good results by modelling the data as a Hidden Markov Model. In the transition matrix, if I don't allow a later state to transition to an earlier state, this produces a tree.